# Call a WebAPI using power apps Patch() function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I just started exploring PowerApps and I am finding it hard to understand all the features it does/doesnot support.

My requirement is to build a datatable(grid) with checkboxes in one of the column and update it to my Mysql database when the user checks/unchecks the checkbox.

I created a table in the Data section by using the GetData option by giving the link to my WebAPI which fetches the data that I need.

I created a canvas app and added a gallery to make it look like a grid(Datatable).

Now, onCheck event of the checkbox I want to use the Patch function to update the datasource.

But the problem is that Patch only updates the table created in my PowerApps but not my table in MySql database.

Is there a way to update MySql Db either directly or via an API call using the Patch function?

It would really help if there is another easier way to achieve this other than using Patch.

Comment: Have you set up a Connector to your MySQL data source? Note, this appears to not be free.

http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/connecting-to-mysql-postgresql


https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 0):

Good question with a rather simple answer. To solve your communication, you have a few options:

1. You can create a custom connector in your environment which communicates with your API, so for example a POST operation that creates the records in your database.
2. Use a premium connector to use your database in PowerApps directly
3. Use an external automation tool like Power Automate.

If you go with the Power Automate tool, you can send your collection to Power Automate (For example an action on a button), which will do the processing for you. Your flow will be built as follow:

- Respond on a PowerApps Request
- Apply to each item
- Create/Update/Delete appropriate item

G'luck